# Old CNAD800-EF USB ADSL Modem Drivers For Windows 7

Tags: drivers

I have an old USB DSL modem that I am trying to get to work with Windows 7.  It is a [CNet CNAD800-EF](http://www.cnet.com.tw/product/cnad800-ef.htm) and the latest official drivers available are for Windows XP.

[image: CNet CNAD800-EF]

Is there any way I can find Windows 7 drivers for this DSL modem, or use my Windows XP drivers under Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need the driver CD for a DSL modem? You should be able to configure the modem via an online interface. For instance to access my DSL I go to 192.168.1.1 in my browser and I can login to the device and configure. The modem should be independent of any hardware using it.

Simply connect an ethernet cable from the modem to your PC. Reboot the PC. Then open up your browser and then try some of the typical logins like http://192.168.1.1, http://192.168.0.1, etc..

Comment: Here is a link to download the drivers:

http://www.helpdrivers.com
Go to modems > Cnet > CNAD-800-EF

Comment: thnx ,I downloaded that drivers its not working for my modem, I have same model no but it does not work for , its maiden china, we can configure router this way we can't configure modem in this way

Comment: In any event you dont need driver to configure a modem, there has to be an online interface you can access. Have you tried calling CNET to see if they can forward you a user guide or to ask them how you can configure it via IP?

Comment: nop I didn't call them , there site has a file to download , it only contains the picture of the modem , not the drivers of the modem.

Comment: Not all DSL modems are attached via Ethernet.  Ones that aren't will not have the web interface.  This one clearly has no such interface, as documented on the site linked.